# How to find all the courses in which the set of enrolled students is a superset of the students who have enrolled in some course C

Tags: sql

I was thinking on the SQL query in a student database:

student(sid,sname)
,course(cid,cname)
,enrol(sid,cid)

If I need to find all the courses in which the set of enrolled students is a superset of the students who have enrolled in some course C, how will this query be written?

Comment: Is this a homework question? ;)

Comment: What have you tried so far? We're glad to help, but we don't generally pass out free answers here unless you show some effort on your part.

Comment: i just posed a sample question, i was thinking whether we can find superset/subset using a SQL query or not. as for the above one, i could not find how will i check that.

Comment: i tried with this query: select cid from enrol where sid in (select sid from enrol where cid=5) 
but then, how to check subset ?

Comment: if we compare the count of the number of tuples, can this check ??

Answer (score 0):

```
Select S.sid, s.sname
from student s 
join enrol e on e.sid = s.sid
join course c on c.cid = e.cid
where c.name = 'c1'
```

Comment: how will this check that the set is superset?